# Mysql select for gaps in rows with min and max data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with min and max value columns, which may have overlapping data.

Example

```
+--------+--------+
| Minval | Maxval |
+--------+--------+
|   0000 |   1000 |
|   1500 |   8999 |
|   0100 |   0200 |
|   5000 |   6999 |
+--------+--------+
```

The possible ranges for min and max values are 0000-9999.

I'm looking for a way to find gaps (holes) in the data. With the above data, the gaps would be 1001-1499 and 9000-9999.

I'm working with php and mysql.

Comment: What is the datatype for min and max varchar? Why not int? Why are there leading zeroes?

Comment: Why are you storing integer values in char columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result can be returned by MySQL query, without a script.

```
SELECT CONCAT(LPAD(r.lo,4,'0'),'-',LPAD(r.hi,4,'0')) AS gap
     , r.lo
     , r.hi
--   , d.minval IS NULL AS gap
--   , d.*
  FROM ( SELECT rl.lo, rh.hi
           FROM (SELECT 0000 AS lo UNION 
                 SELECT rlo.maxval+1
                   FROM example1 rlo
                  WHERE rlo.maxval < 9999
                 ) rl
            JOIN (SELECT 9999 AS hi UNION
                  SELECT rhi.minval-1
                    FROM example1 rhi
                   WHERE rhi.minval > 0000
                 ) rh
              ON rh.hi >= rl.lo
           GROUP BY rl.lo, rh.hi
       ) r
  LEFT
  JOIN example1 d
    ON r.lo BETWEEN d.minval+0 AND d.maxval+0
    OR r.hi BETWEEN d.minval+0 AND d.maxval+0
    OR d.minval+0 BETWEEN r.lo AND r.hi
    OR d.maxval+0 BETWEEN r.lo AND r.hi
 WHERE d.minval IS NULL
 ORDER
    BY r.lo, r.hi
--   , d.minval, d.maxval
```

The approach I used was to start with a set of all possible gaps. We know that every potential gap will:

- start at `0000` or any `maxval+1`
- end at `9999` or any `minval-1`

So, we can generate a list of all possible "gap start" and a list of all possible "gap end". (I was thinking of these as "ranges" when I wrote the query. I used aliases for the inline views, `r` for "range", `rh` for the "high" end of the range, and `rl` for the "low" end of the range.

The inline view assigned the alias "`r`" returns all possible rows that might be a gap. (It's almost a cross join, but we eliminate rows where r.hi would be less than r.lo. I think the actual term that's used for this is "inequality join".)

The anti-join pattern back to the original range table eliminates the rows that aren't real gaps, because there's some overlap with one of the ranges in the table. (The anti-join pattern is a LEFT JOIN and then a predicate in the WHERE clause to eliminate rows were the LEFT JOIN operation found a match, so we are left with rows that didn't have a match. As an alternative, the same elimination can be accomplished using a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` approach.)

(This query will also return a gap of `0000-9999` when there are no rows in the range table.)

To setup test case (I adjusted the OP `0000` value to `0055` to demonstrate that this will identify a gap that starts a `0000`.)

```
CREATE TABLE `example1` (minval INT(4), maxval INT(4));
INSERT INTO `example1` VALUES (0055,1000),(1500,8999),(0100,0200),(5000,6999);


gap           lo     hi
---------  -----  -----
0000-0054      0     54
1001-1499   1001   1499
9000-9999   9000   9999
```

**EDIT**

I just noticed that OP comment that the datatype is CHAR(4), I'd assumed it was integer type, likely `INT(4) ZEROFILL`. The query above will also work CHAR types, but we need to make sure the CHAR gets converted to integer, and the easiest way to do that is adding " + 0 " to the column references, that adjustment is made, and tested.

```
CREATE TABLE `example1` (minval CHAR(4), maxval CHAR(4));
INSERT INTO `example1` VALUES ('0055','1000')
  ,('1500','8999'),('0100','0200'),('5000','6999');
```

Comment: This is more complete. Thanks for the explanation as well. I'm still trying to parse the how of it.

Comment: @Chinaski: the trick is that query `r` (you can run just that separately) to generate every possible range. `rl` gets every possible "min" for a possible gap, `rh` gets every possible "max" for a possible gap. we do a join, and get every possible gap. (the only combinations of lo and hi that won't be a gap is when hi is less than lo. the next trick is the "anti-join"... to find out which of all of those possible gaps aren't really gaps, because they overlap at least one value in a defined range. we throw out rows that match, and what we have left is the real gaps (no overlap with a range.)

Comment: @Chinaski: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will find people here that want to help you; please don't be discouraged by the downvotes and votes to close the question (the downvoters have a reason for what they do; and it's not about you.)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need php code.  You can do this in SQL.

A gap is going to start at one more than a maxval and end at one less than a minval.  You then just have to see if a particular record participates in a gap.

```
select t.*,
       t.maxval+1 as gapStart,
       (select min(t2.minval) - 1
        from t t2
        where t2.minval > t.maxval
       ) as gapEnd
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t.maxval + 1 between t2.minval and t2.maxval
                 )
```

Comment: That is a winner. Thanks for this.

Comment: +1. I concur that resultset can be returned with just MySQL. But there's an edge case which I don't think this handles: a gap starting at `0000`. (For example, if that `(0000,1000)` row was changed to be `(0055,1000)`). I was taking a similar approach. I generated the set of all possible gaps (we know that any gap will start and end at 0000, 9999, a minval-1, or a maxval+1. It's straightforward to get the entire set of all "possible gaps" (a cross join omitting minval>maxval, I had to UNION in the 0000 and 9999). What's not working in my query is eliminating all the rows that aren't real gaps.

Comment: @Chinaski . . . As a note, if you want to handle the two edge cases, you can do that with `union all` statements, comparing to the smallest minval and largest maxval.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need a PHP code

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE (NUMBER_VALUE INT);

INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE VALUES (1,2,3,....9999);
```

you can do this with php loop or create a constant query once and reuse it

Then for each row in the main table do a

```
DELETE FROM TEMP_TABLE WHERE NUMBER_VALUE BETWEEN MINVAL AND MAXVAL;
```

Once deleted you will be left with the gaps but all the numbers.  Then you can loop through these to store the min and max in PHP

Comment: is the most efficient approach to this really temp tables...?

Comment: What's the best way to convert the list of values back into a range, e.g. `'1001-1499'` rather than reporting the gaps as `'1001-1001'`,`'1002-1002'`,`'1003-1003'`, etc.

Comment: @James - I dont think thats the most efficient, but solves the purpose fully

Comment: @spencer7593 PHP loop that runs through and checks if there is a value next to it, if not report it as a gap start and go on till newer consecutive values, while the accepted answer can also be fine tuned